# How to replace meta tags with something else

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have a big problem with meta tag. More precisely:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

I have a program that automatically "push" things on eBay (with template). I want responsive template (it is made on bootstrap), but I can not use these tags because this program (literally) cuts it. At this point, all my work on the template goes in vain. Can someone colud help me?

Comment: what kind of help you need?

Comment: Can I replace the above text with something else? CSS, HTML or JavaScript? Even the lack of a declaration at the top of page destroy this template, and program cuts all of the code at the top.

Comment: you can try with js, though I doubt that it will work

Comment: I guess that You don't have any ideas?

Comment: You should be asking eBay [this question](http://pages.ebay.com/help/policies/listing-javascript.html) since they're pretty explicit about what you can and can't do in their own documentation.

Comment: Ebay works fine, but this program (Linnworks) is sucks. Anyway I ask Linnworks. Thx :)